# Running the PC version of Minecraft on a Pi

Tags: java, opengles, minecraft

In my never ending quest to try and get a Raspberry Pi to run the full PC version of Minecraft, I think I came across something that could help. I nearly have the program booting up on its own.

I'm using a tricked out version of [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/) that disabled GL 1.3-1.4 support, and a project by [Lunixbochs called GLShim](https://github.com/lunixbochs/glshim), [further forked by Ptitseb](https://github.com/ptitSeb/gl4es) for use on the [Open Pandora](https://pyra-handheld.com/boards/). He already has a proof of concept running on the Pandora, but when I tried to get it to run on Pi, Java crashes.

http://pastebin.com/ui4GneEK

Any ideas? As I am currently stuck on this.

Comment: Follow these steps at your own risk: [How to setup Minecraft 1.12.1 on Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=186547)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was not possible at the time of the original question, but the full Java-based Minecraft can run on a Raspberry Pi 2 or higher today. With improvements to OpenGL on Raspbian over the years, LWJGL now just uses full OpenGL via the Mesa library.

Instructions with demo videos:

- [How to setup Minecraft 1.8.9 on RaspPi2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=137279) (original tutorial with Minecraft 1.8.9, requires Stretch/Jessie desktop images with preinstalled Java 8)
- [How to setup Minecraft 1.12.2 on Pi3 or Pi4](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243946) (updated for Minecraft 1.12.2, using Optifine, Raspbian Buster)

I can attest that the basic setup works out of the box on my Pi 3B+. You can get something up and running quickly even if the engine stutters and it renders at about 10 fps. From there, you can dramatically improve the experience via OptiFine, overclocking, or other tips that you'll find in those threads and related videos.

I'm sure the OP became well-aware of this along his neverending quest, but hopefully the answer helps others who stumble upon this question.

Note: The OP's idea of using a GL->GLES shim was on the right track at the time. [gl4es](https://github.com/ptitSeb/gl4es) can be used today to render Minecraft on boards such as the Pi Zero that do not support full OpenGL. However, for these niche cases the game remains unplayable due to the limited RAM.

Comment: It should be noted that Minecraft dropped support of 32-bit systems with version 1.13, so 1.12.2 is the last release that has a chance to work on 32-bit Raspbian. Also, it's very playable on an RPi 4.

Comment: 1.14 runs on 32-bit armhf. The idea of later Java edition versions being 64-bit only is not uncommon, but from what I can tell it's a misconception that arose when LWJGL3 dropped 32-bit Windows x86 and Linux i386 builds. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=245947&p=1522066#p1522066

Answer (score 3):

From the log you pasted it seems that Pi's GPU doesn't know OpenGL. That's one of the reasons they've made a special version of the game.

**EDIT**: I tried to make LWJGL program an run it on pi. It failed. Pi's GPU definitely doesnt support LWJGL OpenGL implementation.

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 is not the same as a full blown OpenGL 2.0...!

Comment: AFAIK OpenPandora and RPi both support OpenGL ES 2.0, so there's no reason Minecraft would work on one device but not on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Running Minecraft Java edition on a Pi does take a bit of work. It does require you to have a Minecraft account. The problem is that minecraft 1.12.2 is the latest version (currently) that can be run on a Pi. A Pi 2B or better is required to get decent fps.
I have added forge and updated rpiMike's script (from raspberry pi forums) so that you can play Minecraft 1.12.2 + optifine or Minecraft 1.12.2 +forge (+ optifine). Optifine is recommended to be able to change more settings to get better FPS.

Tutorial: https://html.dynu.net/index.php/how-to-setup-minecraft-on-raspberry-pi-forge-version-1-12-2/

Comment: How is this different than the top answer?

Comment: My tutorial provides support for forge, this allows users to add other mods of their choice whilst including optifine to help performance.

Comment: That tutorial is just a rip-off of the original RPi forum [topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=239592). They both refer to the same dropbox blobs.

Comment: This is somewhat true as I built on top of his program. Apart from that I added forge which allows multiple mods to be used at once.