# Can you use the Ubuntu download of Minecraft on a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ubuntu, minecraft

If you happen to be using Ubuntu, can't you just use the alternative download?

Comment: You can run Minecraft 1.12.2 on a Pi3 https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=243946

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running the PC version of Minecraft on a Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22026/running-the-pc-version-of-minecraft-on-a-pi)